# Using 2 Passports on rotation

Tags: schengen, passports, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, new-zealand-citizens

I have a UK passport and a New Zealand passport. Assuming UK is no longer part of the EU, and UK passport holders are allowed visa-free visits to the Schengen Area for 90 in 180 days just like NZ passport holders, can I enter, say Spain, on my NZ passport, stay for 90 days, leave for a day, then re-enter on my UK passport for another 90 days? Therefore basically living in Europe permanently while not exceeding the 90-in-180 limit on either passport? Since I would technically be a tourist, I could, therefore, maintain tax residency (and my job) in the UK?

Comment: In addition to the allowed length of stay issues, you may want to consider allowed activities (working in Spain on a visitor visa is probably a no-no), and of course trying to pretend you are a tax resident elsewhere when you live in Spain is most probably tax evasion. If you want to live in Spain, get a long-term visa which allows you to live there, work there, and pay tax there.

Answer (score 9):

No.

You, as the national of a visa-exempt country, may visit the Schengen Area for up to 90 days per 180-day period. Whether you hold more the one passport from the same country (it is legal in some situations) or hold passports from more than one country is irrelevant. You would still be the same person.

Comment: According to this the Schengen area limits don't apply for certain countries with e NZ passport though? https://www.mfat.govt.nz/assets/NZ-Embassies/Geneva-Switzerland/Border-controls-in-Europe-Schengen.pdf - see the 'bilateral visa waiver' section

Comment: @Dave I would suggest incorporating that information as an extra answer, since these agreements (which are indeed still valid) are generally not known.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Well its not really an answer - original question still applies just with that doc as supporting info

Comment: When [ETIAS](https://www.etiasvisa.com/) is introduced (2022), it will become even more difficult since a preclearence will then be required. How these pre Schengen agreements will be effected is compleatly unknown.

Comment: @Dave the bilateral agreement between New Zealand and Switzerland will allow you to stay in Switzerland even after you have exceeded the 90/180 rule in the rest of the Schengen area, but having a passport from another third country doesn't change the way this agreement works, and the agreement has no effect on how much time you can spend in Spain.  Your best bet is to move to Spain before the end of the year, register as a sole proprietor if need be, and work for your UK employer as a contractor.  You can edit your question or ask a new one. Also see [Expatriates.SE].